# How to display messages from kernel module without using dmesg?

Tags: kernel-module, kernel

In order to display the messages loaded into a kernel module, I can use the command

```
dmesg
```

Is there any alternatives for this command? How this function gets all these kernel messages?

Comment: The kernel also hands those off to syslog, which generally sorts them into files in `/var/log`; there may be some clues about that in `/etc/syslog.conf` or `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and possibly a directory sourced from there.  *How this function gets all these kernel messages?* -- see `man dmesg`.